# floating ads css top not working

Tags: html, css

I've made a floating advertisement. The code is shown below:

```
  <style>
  #adTop {
    left:0;
    position:fixed;
    text-align:center;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:999;
    }
  </style>
  <div id="adTop" style="background-color:#666666;border:3px #cccccc dashed"> 
  <font size="3" color="#FFFFFF">
  <marquee width="70%" scrollamount="5" scrolldelay="20" vspace="5">
  Enjoy! | Recommended Website : <a href="http://web-tool.weebly.com">web-tool.weebly.com</a> | Also check out : <a href="http://myzonehk.weebly.com">myzonehk.weebly.com</a>
  </marquee>
  </font>
  <font size="1" color="#FFFFFF">

  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ads by tool-box.weebly.com
  </font>
  </div>
```

WHen I wanted to add another floating ad under this ad, it didn't worked. the top attribute cannot work and whatever i set it, it's just a little bit from the top.

What can I do?

Also see : tool-box.weebly.com

This is my website. The marquee on the top is the floating ad.

Pls help.

Comment: `marquee`, `font` document level CSS, are you fixing 90s code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i think here is what you are looking for. I changed the code little bit. please check it out.

http://jsbin.com/nubufado/1

HTML -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="adTop"> 
  <marquee width="70%" scrollamount="5" scrolldelay="20" vspace="5">
  Enjoy! | Recommended Website : <a href="http://web-tool.weebly.com">web-tool.weebly.com</a> | Also check out : <a href="http://myzonehk.weebly.com">myzonehk.weebly.com</a>
  </marquee>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class='creator'>Ads by tool-box.weebly.com</p>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS-

```
#adTop {
  background:#666;
  border: 3px #cccccc dashed;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
} 
.creator {
  margin-top: 3px;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 85%;
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Cool idea. But what i want is to create another <div id="adTop2"> so i could place it under the original one with the totally same style.

Answer (score 1):

That is a *fixed* positioned elements. By using `position: fixed;` the element is removed from document normal flow.

Hence if you're going to add another positioned element, you should change the `top` property of the new element.

i.e. you need to set an explicit `height` for the first element, and use that value for `top` property of the second one.

For instance:

```css
#adTop-1, #adTop-2 {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position:fixed;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    z-index:999;
}

#adTop-1 { height: 30px; }

#adTop-2 { top: 30px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest don't use `<font></font` Tag:

Reasons:

1) `<font></font>` is Not Supported/deprecated in HTML5.
2) it's not block element

as you want another add below the first add

use block element here is an example in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HarishBoke/qN9KB/)

Hope this help you or what you are looking for.